# How do I programatically get the file or directory name after extracting after a tar archive?

Tags: command-line, tar

I have a process in my `Dockerfile` with the follow steps:

1. Download the tar file using wget.
2. untar the file.
3. Perform some operation with the file . In this case, move content to another place.

The follow code works until `ffmpeg` version still 3.4.1.
So, today the available version for `ffmpeg` is 3.4.2 and the code is not working.

I want to find a way to grab back the filename after the untar process and pass it to the next steps

```
RUN wget http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
RUN tar xf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
RUN mv ffmpeg-3.4.1-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
RUN mv ffmpeg-3.4.1-64bit-static/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
```

It could be something like this:

```
RUN DIRNAME = tar xf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
RUN mv $DIRNAME/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
RUN mv $DIRNAME/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you retaining multiple versions of the extracted tarball in the directory? if not, you may be able to use a simple filename glob e.g. `mv ffmpeg-*-static/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: @steeldriver this is an excelent solution to my process. And it works. But I will accept the answer related to the question. Thanks to show me another way to do.

Answer (score 6):

Don't. Instead, get tar to put the contents in a directory of your choosing.

1. `tar` can remove *n* components of the path of each file (`--strip-components`)
2. `tar` can apply arbitrary sed expressions to change the path of each file (`--transform`)

So I'd do something like:

```
mkdir ffmpeg
wget -O - http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz |
  tar --xz -x -C ffmpeg --strip-components=1
```

Here, I made the directory myself, and told tar to extract there (the `-C` option), while removing the first component from the path of the extracted files. So `ffmpeg-3.4.1-64bit-static/ffprobe` becomes `ffprobe`  inside the directory `ffmpeg`.

Or:

```
wget -O - http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz |
  tar --xz -x --transform='s:[^/]*/:ffmpeg/'
```

Here, I simply changed the first component of the path to `ffmpeg`, so I didn't need to make the directory myself. So, `ffmpeg-3.4.1-64bit-static/ffmpeg` becomes `ffmpeg/ffmpeg`.

Or, knowing that you specifically want to dump those particular files in `/usr/local/bin`, use `-C` to directly place the files there, while removing all directory components and selecting exactly those files you want to extract:

```
wget -O - http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz |
  tar Jx -C /usr/local/bin --transform='s:.*/::' --wildcards '*/ffmpeg' '*/ffprobe'
```

With any tar, you can specify the files to be extracted. With GNU tar, you can also use wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

The command to get the directory name from the `tar.xz` file is:

```
tar tJvf tar-file-name.tar.xz | head -1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

You'll need to:

1. Get the directory name (e.g. using above solution) and save it in a variable
2. decompress the tar.xz file (e.g. using tar xf command)
3. move the files using the directory variable

---

Explanation how to get the directory name from a `tar` file:

Tar parameters:

```
-f file
-J xz compression
-t list content
-v verbose
```

`head -1` - prints the file line

`awk '{print $6}'` - print the 6th elements which is the directory name

---

Examples:

1. `tar.xz` example:

   tar tJvf coreutils-8.22.tar.xz | head -1 | awk '{print $6}'

Results with:

```
coreutils-8.22/
```

2. `tar.bz2` example for `ffmpeg-3.4.2.tar.bz2`

   tar tjvf ffmpeg-3.4.2.tar.bz2 | head -1 | awk '{print $6}'

Results with:

```
ffmpeg-3.4.2/
```

> Note that for `bz2` compressed files I used the `tar` `j` flag

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
$ tar tf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | head -1 | cut -d '/' -f1
ffmpeg-3.4.2-64bit-static
```

Notice that `GNU tar` does not require `-j`, `-z` etc., it can detect archive type automatically.